# How can we make foreign key among tables after inserting data in those tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have created tables in **sql server**. And i have also inserted data/rows in that tables.

Now i want to make relationship among them means i want to create **foreign key constraints** among them, is it possible ?

Whenever i try to create relationship among table a problem is occured. "Saving changes is permitted, The changes you made required table to re-created and dropped"

Please suggest me what should i do to make relationship(foreign key) among them ?

My Child table design is this

[image: this is my child table]

this is my parent table:-
[image: this is my parent table]

please now right what alter query i should write..?

Comment: `salary` should reference to `roll` ?

Comment: Also, if you want exact query, provide table names. I can see that parent table is called `testing`, can't see the name of the child table.

Comment: child table name is emp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this link
[**"Error message when you try to save a table in SQL Server 2008: "Saving changes is not permitted"**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956176)

Another solution is below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a script like this:

```
 alter table ChildTable
     add constraint FK_ChildTable_ColumnName foreign key (ColumnName) references ParentTable(PrimaryKeyColumnName)
```

[Edit] If I read your description correctly the script would be:

```
 alter table emp
     add constraint FK_emp_salary foreign key(salary) references testing(roll)
```

Comment: My child table design is as following

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because of a feature when using the GUI. If you have a look at this [link](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/BrianKnight/ssis/52/sql-server-2008-designer-behavior-change-saving-changes-not-permitted-1) it shows you how to work round it. It is a feature which prevents you from dropping and recreating the table which is what SSMS does in the background when you click ok.

The code provided by the previous posted is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add foreign constraints that aren't violated by existing data. You may also have to add suitable indices first, although this depends on the DBMS. In any case, first make sure your existing data is compatible with the foreign keys you want to introduce. In other words, if you were to create the foreign key first, and then insert the data, you should not produce any foreign key violations.